# Rails Admin. How to select a column to be shown instead of the row id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-admin

Hi guys I have a couple of foreign keys in a table A and i Would Like to select a specific column in table B to be shown to the user instead of the column b id's.

Maybe the picture helps understanding:

[image]

Here, instead of shown `Tag #1, Tag #2, Tag #3, Tag #4` I would like to shown the column name of each of these Tags.

Comment: Can you include the code that produces this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default rails admin uses the name attribute of an instance to display them.
But i think is better practice to give them their own rails admin specific name as often you'll want the name to be relevant to your operations team and not necessarily to your end users,

With that said you can tell rails admin what method to use adding this line on the initializer config file.

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :rails_admin_title }
```

And then you would implement that instance method on your tag model

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
   def rails_admin_title
      "#{self.name} #{self.id}"
   end 
end
```

Comment: You, sir are a genious!
Thank you!